# ZPL String obelisk

Tags: zpl

I'm learning ZPL through the code of a previous developer at my company. I've written 3 new labels so far, and rewriting our application from his ASP VB to PHP..

Anyway. One of the labels he wrote starts with an obelisk instead of the normal ^XA.

I was wondering if anybody out there knew what the obelisk symbol actually means.. I looked through the ZPL manual 
https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf

This is his code for the that label (I replaced the special character with {{obelisk}} to make sure there wasn't any encoding problems when posting to SO):

```
StartNum = "M" & (Convert.ToInt32(StartNum.Substring(1, 8)) + 1).ToString("D8")
p1 = "{{obelisk}}CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR6,6~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ^XA^MMT^PW711^LL0152^LS0^BY6,3,72^FT52,83^BCN,,Y,N^FD>:C>5"
p2 = "^FS^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ"
PrinterConfig = PrinterConfig & p1 & StartNum.Substring(1) & p2
```

Edit: Attached screenshot of the character:
[image]

Comment: Maybe take a screenshot of the obelisk so we can better see it?

Comment: Added to the OP

Comment: Since I'm not sure I won't post this as an answer but check out http://labelary.com/viewer.html if you haven't already, you can play around with the ZPL code in there and see a label being generated. I think It's possible that it was just a typo that generated the ASCII?  if you ommit the`†` it doesn't cause any issues.

Comment: that online editor has been a god send! I used that to design the labels I did create. Anyway, when I remove that character it doesn't effect the label itself, so I am assuming you're correct about the typo. His ZPL isn't valid so I was wondering if maybe it was short hand for a default opening or something. Anyway thanks for taking the time to help me out!!!

Comment: Anytime! Glad to help.